# Type Error when passing an object into a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, parameters, typeerror

For a school project I am creating a billing system for a local nursery. Each bill is an object with the attributes `startmonth` (the first month to bill from), `endmonth` (the last month to bill to) and `childName`.

```py
class calculate_bill:
    def __init__(self, startmonth, endmonth, childName):
        self.startmonth = startmonth
        self.endmonth = endmonth
        self.childName = childName`
```

I have used a tkinter dropdown to get the desired months and pass the selected month into a function. However, when i try and run this I get the error;

> TypeError: startmonth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bill'

Not sure what this means or how to solve it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
def startmonth(self, m1, bill):
    bill.startmonth = m1
    print(bill.startmonth)
```

Comment: Please add the code that you were running when you received the error, the error means that you aren't passing enough arguments into the method when it's called

Comment: Show the code that calls `startmonth()`. Is it defined inside a class? If not, why does it have a `self` parameter?

Comment: ***Not sure what this means***: Possible explanation: The `def startmonth(...` **is not a class methode**. Therefore your passed two arguments, `(m1, bill`), are assigned from left to right. The third argument `bill` can't be fulfiled which leads to: ***required positional argument: 'bill'***

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to make sense of the code you shared, and I assume that `startmonth` is a method of the `calculate_bill` class, everything OK so far, but you're missing two things:

1. Your function and class attributes are ambiguous, `startmonth` is the name of an attribute **and** a method. Change one of the two to something else.
2. The function `startmonth` already receives the bill: it's called `self`, so you don't need to pass `bill` as an argument. The first argument of an instance method is always itself, and traditionally called `self`, although not necessarily.

This is a more valid representation of what are you trying to do:

```
class CalculateBill:
    def __init__(self, startmonth, endmonth, childName):
        self.startmonth = startmonth
        self.endmonth = endmonth
        self.childName = childName`

    def set_startmonth(self, m1):
        self.startmonth = m1
        print(self.startmonth)
```

Some pointers about this code:

1. Try to use CamelCase for class names, it makes them more easy to identify.
2. `set_startmonth` doesn't need the `bill` argument. it already has it, with `self`.
3. It's perfectly normal to write methods to set instance attributes, read about "setters"